# How to automatically redeploy JAR?

Tags: java, deployment, jar

I deploy my application as executable JAR file. The workflow is something like:

1. Fix bug or add a new feature;
2. Build executable JAR using Maven;
3. Copy JAR on production server over scp;
4. Connect to production sever over SSH;
5. Reconnect to screen in which app is running;
6. Stop running app with Ctrl+C;
7. Execute app with java -jar my_app.jar;
8. Check if the app is running fine using log file.

There are a few JARs that run on production server, each in its own screen.

I want to have some tool that will do all this steps automatically. Quick Google search didn't provided a useful answer. Tools like Glu of Chief seem like overkill in my scenario.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered a JavaEE application server, such as JBoss? It may also seem like overkill, but it will allow you you redeploy applications over a simple web interface. Also, I'm not very familiar with Maven, but isn't this the type of thing it was designed for?

Comment: @etherous, I thought about application server or container, but my application is a console app that just does some processing of data. I don't really like to put its code into servlets to be able to run it in application server. The main goal of maven is building applications from source code. It can help with deploying app in servlet container or application server with some plugins, but I've not found any plugins that allow to deploy executable JArs.

Comment: You know, application servers aren't just about servlets. You can write some powerful applications without a single servlet. But you're right, it seems overkill for such a task. Is this something which runs periodically, at intervals, tiggered by events, or is always running?

Comment: @etherous, all JARs are running always, except situations when one of them crashed or stopped manually.

Comment: Sounds like you need a simple, custom solution. A little batch script would do it

Comment: @etherous, yeah, that was one of my first thoughts when I've started thinking about this problem. But decided that maybe one of SO members knows the better way :-)